# How to simulate a "Full Queue" on ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

We recently had some issues in our testing environment when ActiveMQ ran out of system resources.

How can I simulate this scenario locally in order to reproduce the issue and test potential fixes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to simulate the scenario by changing the ActiveMQ config.

You can set the system resources available in ActiveMQ's configuration file, which you can find at `libexec/conf/activemq.xml` in your ActiveMQ installation directory.

For example, you can change the default values:

```
  <systemUsage>
    <systemUsage>
        <memoryUsage>
            <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
        </memoryUsage>
        <storeUsage>
            <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
        </storeUsage>
        <tempUsage>
            <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
        </tempUsage>
    </systemUsage>
  </systemUsage>
```

To tiny values instead:

```
  <systemUsage>
    <systemUsage>
        <memoryUsage>
            <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="1" />
        </memoryUsage>
        <storeUsage>
            <storeUsage limit="512 kb"/>
        </storeUsage>
        <tempUsage>
            <tempUsage limit="512 kb"/>
        </tempUsage>
    </systemUsage>
  </systemUsage>
```

Run or restart ActiveMQ and it should fill up very quickly.

More info in the ActiveMQ docs: http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html